# What does fprintf() do in the following macro?

Tags: c, macros

This macro is for error logging. The `LOG_MESSAGE` macro prints filename followed by line number, and finally it prints info/error msg. The argument `prio` determines the priority of message (i.e.whether it is information message or error) and `stream` may be `STD_OUT`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INFO    1
#define ERR 2
#define STD_OUT stdout
#define STD_ERR stderr
#define LOG_MESSAGE(prio, stream, msg, ...)
do {\
    char *str;\
    if (prio == INFO)\
        str = "INFO";\
    else if (prio == ERR)\
        str = "ERR";\
    fprintf(stream, "[%s] : %s : %d : "msg" \n", \
    str, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
} while (0)

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "Hello";

        /* display normal message */
    LOG_MESSAGE(ERR, STD_ERR, "Failed to open file");

    /* provide string as argument */
    LOG_MESSAGE(INFO, STD_OUT, "%s Geeks for Geeks", s);

    /* provide integer as arguments */
    LOG_MESSAGE(INFO, STD_OUT, "%d + %d = %d", 10, 20, (10 + 20));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seriously. What do you think the live rendering preview is for?!

Comment: Is your question about the `##__VA_ARGS__` portion of the `printf` statement?

Comment: i m asking how fprintf part works

Comment: This won't compile,it's missing a slash.

Comment: @user3130036 Please see my answer below. You can also read more about fprintf from any C reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

> What does fprintf() do in the following macro?

`fprintf` is a function that will write *formatted data* to a *stream*. In the case of the above example, the stream is simply `stream` passed into `LOG_MESSAGE`. If you look at the parameters passed in to the macro, you will see it takes `prio` -> priority, `stream` -> the stream to write to, `msg` -> the actual message to write, and some additional variable arguments.

In `main`, you are choosing between writing to `STD_ERR` and `STD_OUT` streams.

**As an aside:**

Macros are just a copy-paste operation that are performed by the pre-processor before compilation.